# Change the colors provided in gui-colors

Tags: color

If I type `:h gui-colors`, a list of available color names pops up. Often times I just want to change the tone of a color. Assuming these are simple variables of some sort, can I redefine these somehow?

For example: `let &red=&green`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not easily possible. I think those colors mentioned there are predefined in the [source](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/term.c#L6836-L6867).

Most other colors will be read from the distributed file [RGB.txt](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/rgb.txt) in the runtime directory. This file come originally from the X11 source and determines the color definitions for various names. (See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names))

It is not advisable, to change those definitions in the source because this will most likely cause confusion when working on a different system. Instead, define your own color names like

```
:hi MyGreen ctermfg=88 ctermbg=0 guifg=red guibg=NONE
```

and then use the colorname `MyGreen` consistently where you need it.

Comment: Of course, the highlight groups are themselves just color definitions (I didn't know). I can define my own and symlink them. brilliant